# WPF Translating an XAML Animation to C# Code

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I found a great WIPE animation here : http://www.wearerighteous.com/programming/slidewipe-transition-for-your-windows-in-wpf/

> EDIT: the link above is dead so you have to see this one
>   http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/10/03/How-can-I-create-a-e2809cwipee2809d-effect-to-transition-between-two-images-in-WPF.aspx
>   It has the same source code.

Basically, the code there is like this:

```xml
<Window.OpacityMask>
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" x:Name="BlackStop"/>
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent" x:Name="TransparentStop"/>
</LinearGradientBrush> 
<Window.OpacityMask>
    <Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransparentStop"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" By="1"  Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BlackStop"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" By="1" Duration="0:0:1"
                      BeginTime="0:0:0.05" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

I tried to "translate" the animation in c# code and I can't seem to do it. I tried several versions, like :

```
public void WipeAnimation(FrameworkElement ObjectToAnimate)
    { 
        LinearGradientBrush OpacityBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(1,0);
        OpacityBrush.EndPoint   = new Point(0,0);
        GradientStop BlackStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0);
        GradientStop TransparentStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0);
        OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(t);
        OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(t2);
        ObjectToAnimate.OpacityMask = OpacityBrush;

        Duration d = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard() { Duration = d };
        DoubleAnimation DA = new DoubleAnimation() {  By=1 , Duration = d };
        DoubleAnimation DA2 = new DoubleAnimation() { By=1 , Duration = d };
        sb.Children.Add(DA); sb.Children.Add(DA2);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(DA,TransparentStop);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(DA2,BlackStop);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA2, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Or replacing in the SetTarget Rows like :

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(DA, (ObjectToAnimate.OpacityMask as LinearGradientBrush).GradientStops[1]);
```

But nothing happens to my FrameworkElement. I called it for a Window (just like in the example from the site), and the only think that happens is that it sets the OpacityMask. The animation starts and ends (I added a Completed Event to the Storyboard with a MessageBox just to see if it works). I don't know what other things to do.

Please help! :( 
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Maybe I explained the question bad. I'm trying to create the animation that I have in XAML, in C# code.... I've been trying for two days now, searching for a solution. I don't know why the C# version doesn't work ...

Comment: one thing your storyboard does not have in XAML and you have in C# is  {Duration = d}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the above is not working, but here's something that does work - instead of creating a Storyboard, simply use the BeginAnimation() method for each GradientStop:

```
BlackStop.BeginAnimation(GradientStop.OffsetProperty, DA2);
TransparentStop.BeginAnimation(GradientStop.OffsetProperty, DA);
```

Comment: Thank you ! :) At least there's a way to start it ... :P :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void WipeAnimation(FrameworkElement ObjectToAnimate)
{ 
    LinearGradientBrush OpacityBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
    OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(1,0);
    OpacityBrush.EndPoint   = new Point(0,0);
    GradientStop BlackStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0);
    GradientStop TransparentStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0);
    OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(t);
    OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(t2);
    ObjectToAnimate.OpacityMask = OpacityBrush;

    this.RegisterName("TransparentStop", TransparentStop);
    this.RegisterName("BlackStop", BlackStop);

    Duration d = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard() { Duration = d };
    DoubleAnimation DA = new DoubleAnimation() {  By=1 , Duration = d };
    DoubleAnimation DA2 = new DoubleAnimation() { By=1 , Duration = d };
    sb.Children.Add(DA); sb.Children.Add(DA2);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(DA,"TransparentStop");
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(DA2,"BlackStop");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA2, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
    sb.Begin();
}
```

EDIT:

This code is great! But it has 3 errors so i found it. The correct version is here:

```
 public void WipeAnimation(FrameworkElement ObjectToAnimate)
        {
            LinearGradientBrush OpacityBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
            OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(1, 0);
            OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
            GradientStop BlackStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0);
             GradientStop TransparentStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0);
            OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(BlackStop);
            OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(TransparentStop);
            ObjectToAnimate.OpacityMask = OpacityBrush;

            this.RegisterName("TransparentStop", TransparentStop);
            this.RegisterName("BlackStop", BlackStop);

            Duration d = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard() { Duration = d };
            DoubleAnimation DA = new DoubleAnimation() { By = 1, Duration = d };
            DoubleAnimation DA2 = new DoubleAnimation() { By = 1, Duration = d };
            sb.Children.Add(DA); sb.Children.Add(DA2);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(DA, "TransparentStop");
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(DA2, "BlackStop");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA2, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
            sb.Begin(this);
        }
```

Errors line are:

```
OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(t); ->  OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(BlackStop);

OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(t2); -> OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(TransparentStop);

sb.Begin(); ->  sb.Begin(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems to work great in my case.....

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfHierarchicalDataGrid.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window4" 
    MinHeight="100"
    MinWidth="100"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Opacity="0.7"
    WindowState="Normal"
    WindowStyle="None">
  <Window.OpacityMask>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"
                      x:Name="BlackStop"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"
                      x:Name="TransparentStop"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Window.OpacityMask>
  <Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="TransparentStop"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                        By="1"  Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                       Storyboard.TargetName="BlackStop"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" By="1"
                       Duration="0:0:1"
                       BeginTime="0:0:0.05" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Window.Triggers>
  <Grid>
    <Image Source="Water_lilies.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you answer but I think I may have written the question wrong. I want to have the animation in C#. In XAML, it works for me too, but I want to have it written in C#. The c# version isn't working for me. Is it working for you?

Comment: He asked to use C# and not XAML.